# Swift how to set manually photoLibrary and camera authorization?

Tags: swift, authorization

When using my app, the user is asked permission to access camera and library one time (when needed), answering allow or not in the "apple alert" (requestAccess).
I need to add a view where the user can be able to change these authorizations afterwards if he wants. I added switch buttons so the user can make the choice to keep it authorized or not. But I can't find how to set the authorizationStatus.
Is there a way to change the authorizationStatus manually, from .authorized to .denied or opposite ? 
I tried to prompt the apple alert using 'AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess()' but it doesn't show if the user already authorized before.
Any suggestion welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

By security and privacy reasons developers have only one way - use system dialog for requesting authorization for access to protected system services.

But you can suggest for your users a short way to system settings. This code launches the Settings app and displays your app’s custom settings.

```
let settingUrl = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    UIApplication.shared.open(settingUrl!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @AlexSmet , it works well and that's a great way to make it !